# What Azure role allows a user to configure SQL Server firewall rules?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

What Azure role allows a user to configure SQL Server firewall rules?

Assigning the SQL Security Manager role gives me access to most of the server settings but when I click on 'Show Firewall Settings' I get the message No access on the Firewall settings blade.

What role can I assign to the user without giving them complete control of the Azure account.

[image: Show Firewall Settings No Access]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select your SQL Server in the Azure website you can click on the "Access Control (IAM)" menu and add specific Roles or specific Users to that SQL Server.

The "SQL Security Manager" role is designed to give access to security aspects of a SQL Server. so you can give your user this role to let them play with the firewall settings.

[image]

Comment: This works but first I had to close out my browser window and re-open it. Thanks.

Comment: Even with this permission I got this error. Interestingly it's complaining I don't have read privileges but I can actually see all the rules: `Failed to overwrite firewall rules for server: XXXXdb and refresh the blade. ErrorCode: undefined ErrorMessage: The client 'live.com#XXXXX@yahoo.com' with object id 'XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX-xxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/locations/firewallRulesOperationResults/read' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/westus/firewallRulesOperationResults/XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`

Comment: Even more interestingly the firewall rules could be displayed, edited, saved (and take effect) but it cannot then redisplay them without refreshing. I give up!